# Worksheet Selection Change is not firing

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Macro enabled file.  I have 3 methods / functions in my Module1.

1. Worksheet_SelectionChange
2. Button1_Click
3. MyMacro

Button1 fires when I click on my button in the worksheet.  MyMacro fires when called from the Button1_Click.  My Worksheet_SelectionChange method does not fire when I change cells or when I change worksheets.  I would like a method that fires when I exit a cell.  I jave tried various samples from the web.  They all have a Worksheet_SelectionChange method in their samples.  What do I have to do to trigger a method when I leave a cell?  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = True
MsgBox "TEST"
End Sub

Sub Button1_Click()
BR = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
COL = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Worksheets("942").Range("A" + CStr(BR)).Value
FileName = FileName & "_"
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
RandomNumber = Int((999 - 100 + 1) * Rnd + 100)
Worksheets("942").Range("J" + CStr(BR)).Value = FileName
MyMacro
End Sub


Private Sub MyMacro()
MsgBox " I just left A2", 0, ""
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll have to move the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` sub to the worksheet (module). Just right-click on the tab and select `View Code` this is where it should be.

Comment: AFAIK, `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` should be in a Worksheet module. Is it in a worksheet module, or workbook module?

Comment: Thanks Ralph and BruceWayne!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to move the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` sub to the worksheet (module). Just right-click on the tab and select View Code this is where it should be.

That's because the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` can be different for each sheet. By placing it on a particular sheet Excel knows when the even should fire.

[image]