# How do I copy information of one cell to a cell on another worksheet, when a specific cell is clicked?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to create a VBA macro that when I click on a certain cell (in excel), the information on another worksheet can get copied into the designated cells.

For instance, if I click on A1 in Worksheet1, then B20:C20 on worksheet3 is copied to B20:C20 of Worksheet2. Can anyone help me create this macro?

Comment: Look into the [Worksheet_SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470.aspx) event

Comment: Use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event

Comment: Maybe this post can help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863950/worksheet-selection-change-is-not-firing

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this example below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("KeyInformation")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Factsheet")
    ws.Range("A2:Q2").Copy
    ws1.Range("B9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ws1.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed this a little and it started to work.